# Making each props title a different color

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I've coded Profile cards in React using `props`:

```
const Profilebox = props => (
<div className="Profilebox">
    <img src={props.image} />
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    <h2>{props.subtitle}</h2>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
</div>)
```

Is it possible to use a different `h2` color for each Card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const Profilebox = props => (
   <div className="Profilebox">
      <img src={props.image} />
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <h2 style={props.style}>{props.subtitle}</h2>
      <p>{props.text}</p>
   </div>)
```

You could had the style down in the props. Or you could right a function that would randomly select a color and set the color that way.

```
 randomColorStyle = () => {

     return{color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);}
 }

 const Profilebox = props => (
   <div className="Profilebox">
      <img src={props.image} />
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <h2 style={this.randomColorStyle}>{props.subtitle}</h2>
      <p>{props.text}</p>
   </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to pass a different color to the Card from its parent. Assuming you are mapping through props to assign the appropriate data to each card, you'd be able to add another prop. In the parent, something silly like:

```
const colorArray = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "black", "purple"];
profileCardData.map(profileCard => {
  let color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
  return (
    <Profilebox image={image} text={text} style={color} subtitle={subtitle}/>
  )
```

Then, in your Profilebox you'd do a quick inline style:

```
const Profilebox = props => (
<div className="Profilebox">
    <img src={props.image} />
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    <h2 style={props.style}>{props.subtitle}</h2>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
</div>)
```

It would be super easy to assign different colors in other ways. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below snippet helps.

```js
const Profilebox = props => (
<div className="Profilebox">
    <img src={props.image || null} />
    <h1>{props.title || 'default Title'}</h1>
    
    <h2 className={`bg_${Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3))+1}`}>{props.subtitle || 'default subtitle'}</h2>
    <p>{props.text || 'default Text'}</p>
</div>)

const Profiles = () => (<div><Profilebox image = ''/><Profilebox  image = ''/></div>)

ReactDOM.render(<Profiles/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.Profilebox {
border : 1px solid gray;
width:50%;
}

.bg_1{
  color:green;
}
.bg_2{
  color:red;
}
.bg_3{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
</div>
```